# if/else and parameter placement C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have recently begun C++ and am trying to understand syntax, but I'm having placement problems. I have to do a credit card validation function that asks for a valid credit card and then I have to print out the type of credit card.

My only issue is with the if-statements for determining the credit card type. I don't know where exactly to place them and whether or not I'm missing any brackets or such.

The exact chunk that's problematic for me is:

```
        if(c.substr(0, 2) == "65" || c.substr(0, 5) == "6011" || c.substr(0, 7) >= "622126" && c.substr(0, 7) <= "622925" || c.substr(0, 4) >= "644" && c.substr(0, 4) <= "649")
            s = "You have a Discover card";
        if(c.substr(0, 2) >= "51" && c.substr(0, 2) <= "55")
            s = "You have a MasterCard card";
        if(c.substr(0, 1) == "4")
            s = "You have a Visa card";
        if(c.substr(0, 2) == "34" || c.substr(0, 2) == "37")
            s = "You have an American Express card";
```

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void validateCC();
string checkCC(string, int, bool&);
bool validateCCNum(string);

void main() {
    char again;
    cout << "Validate a credit card number (Y/N)? ";
    cin >> again;
    while (toupper(again) == 'Y') {
        validateCC();
        cout << "Validate a credit card number (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> again;
    }
}

void validateCC() {
    string ccn, msg;
    bool OK;
    int ccLen;
    cout << "Please enter a 15 or 16 digit credit card number."
        << "\n(No spaces or hyphens): ";
    cin >> ccn;
    ccLen = ccn.length();
    msg = checkCC(ccn, ccLen, OK);
    if(!OK)
        cout << msg;
    else
        if(validateCCNum(ccn))
            cout << "Valid credit card number\n";
        else
            cout << "Invalid credit card number\n";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}

string checkCC(string c, int cLen, bool& ccOK) {
    string s = "";
    ccOK = true;
    for(int i=0;i<cLen && ccOK;++i)
        ccOK = isdigit(c[i]);

        if(c.substr(0, 2) == "65" || c.substr(0, 5) == "6011" || c.substr(0, 7) >= "622126" && c.substr(0, 7) <= "622925" || c.substr(0, 4) >= "644" && c.substr(0, 4) <= "649")
            s = "You have a Discover card";
        if(c.substr(0, 2) >= "51" && c.substr(0, 2) <= "55")
            s = "You have a MasterCard card";
        if(c.substr(0, 1) == "4")
            s = "You have a Visa card";
        if(c.substr(0, 2) == "34" || c.substr(0, 2) == "37")
            s = "You have an American Express card"; 

    if(ccOK == false) {
        s = "Invalid credit card number digits";
    } else if(cLen == 15) {
        if(c.substr(0, 2) != "34" && c.substr(0, 2) != "37") {
            ccOK = false;
            s = "Invalid American Express credit card number";
        }
    } else if(cLen != 16) {
        ccOK = false;
        s = "Invalid credit card number length";
    }
    return s;
}

bool validateCCNum(string cc) {
    bool flip = true;
    int tmp, num = 0;
    int ccLen = cc.length()-1;
    for(int ndx=ccLen;ndx>=0;ndx--) {
            if(flip)
                num += cc[ndx] - '0';
            else {
                tmp = (cc[ndx] - '0') * 2;
                if(tmp <= 9)
                    num += tmp;
                else
                    num += (1 + (tmp - 10)); // max of 18
            }
            flip = !flip;
    }
    return num % 10 == 0;
}
```

I don't know whether the problematic chunk belongs where it currently is, or if I place it in the validateCC() section and then add a parameter for it.

Thank you.

Comment: Make a simple test program and figure out how conditionals work yourself?

Comment: You should add parenthesis around each condition in the `if` parameters to play it safe.

Comment: Extract some functions. Group you conditionals to make it easier to read and reason about, and test them separately.

Comment: In its current state, running it will just display that the credit card is balid or invalid, but completely skips the credit card type. I've just tried placing it after the approval for the credit card, but I get errors.

Comment: OMG -1 for 90% unnecessary code, not having put any effort in trying (to find a solution) yourself and for tagging this `credit-card`.

Comment: Already tested the code i posted in the answer section, used a new function to check the card type and is called only when the card is valid. Message me if you want more information about it.

Comment: And while we're at it: `if ( ccOK == false )` is an anti-pattern, which suggests that you don't understand what a boolean is.  If `ccOK` is of type `bool`, `if ( ! ccOK )` is the way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the substrings to int (stringVar >> IntVar;) so you can evaluate the <= >= etc...

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void validateCC();
string checkCC(string, int, bool&);
bool validateCCNum(string);

void main() {
    char again;
    cout << "Validate a credit card number (Y/N)? ";
    cin >> again;
    while (toupper(again) == 'Y') {
        validateCC();
        cout << "Validate a credit card number (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> again;
    }
}
string checkCardType(string c){
if(atoi(c.substr(0, 2).c_str()) == 65 || atoi(c.substr(0, 5).c_str()) == 6011 || atoi(c.substr(0, 7).c_str()) >= 622126 && atoi(c.substr(0, 7).c_str()) <= 622925 || atoi(c.substr(0, 4).c_str()) >= 644 && atoi(c.substr(0, 4).c_str()) <= 649)
            return "You have a Discover card";
        if(atoi(c.substr(0, 2).c_str()) >= 51 && atoi(c.substr(0, 2).c_str()) <= 55)
            return "You have a MasterCard card";
        if(atoi(c.substr(0, 1).c_str()) == 4)
            return "You have a Visa card";
        if(atoi(c.substr(0, 2).c_str()) == 34 || atoi(c.substr(0, 2).c_str()) == 37)
            return "You have an American Express card"; 
        return "Card not recognized";
}
void validateCC() {
    string ccn, msg;
    bool OK;
    int ccLen;
    cout << "Please enter a 15 or 16 digit credit card number."
        << "\n(No spaces or hyphens): ";
    cin >> ccn;
    ccLen = ccn.length();
    msg = checkCC(ccn, ccLen, OK);
    if(!OK)
        cout << msg;
    else
        if(validateCCNum(ccn)){
            cout << "Valid credit card number\n";
            cout << checkCardType(ccn);}
        else
            cout << "Invalid credit card number\n";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}

string checkCC(string c, int cLen, bool& ccOK) {
    string s = "";
    ccOK = true;
    for(int i=0;i<cLen && ccOK;++i)
        ccOK = isdigit(c[i]);

    if(ccOK == false) {
        s = "Invalid credit card number digits";
    } else if(cLen == 15) {
        if(c.substr(0, 2) != "34" && c.substr(0, 2) != "37") {
            ccOK = false;
            s = "Invalid American Express credit card number";
        }
    } else if(cLen != 16) {
        ccOK = false;
        s = "Invalid credit card number length";
    }
    return s;
}

bool validateCCNum(string cc) {
    bool flip = true;
    int tmp, num = 0;
    int ccLen = cc.length()-1;
    for(int ndx=ccLen;ndx>=0;ndx--) {
            if(flip)
                num += cc[ndx] - '0';
            else {
                tmp = (cc[ndx] - '0') * 2;
                if(tmp <= 9)
                    num += tmp;
                else
                    num += (1 + (tmp - 10)); // max of 18
            }
            flip = !flip;
    }
    return num % 10 == 0;
}
```

Comment: First, of course, the number might not fit in an `int`.  And the tests he's doing are more complex if done on an integral type than if done on a string.

Comment: It fits ¬_¬ he is using substrings of no more than 8 chars long (99,999,999... Check the code...INTEGER*4 
    ---------
    Size:           4 bytes (32 bits, bit 31 = sign)
    Value range:    -2147483648 to 2147483647

Comment: After making a bunch of different functions, I finally found the solution and it was this one. I cannot express my gratitude enough for this solution.

Comment: He's dealing with strings of 15 or 16 digits.  There's no need for substrings in the solution, and no need to convert to `int`; it's much simpler to do pattern matching on the initial string, without introducing lots of extra variables.

Comment: What about the ranges? You will make a pattern matching for each value? There is no extra variables, just data conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this works:

c.substr(0, 2) == "34"

Why don't you just parse the String to an integer (atoi) and then compare it with '=='. Also strings are compared with "string".compare("string2") (which returns 0 if its the same string).

Comment: If you check the substr, it means that its not taking the whole credit card number. To check the ranges of values, he need to convert to int.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña Why?  He can compare strings just as well.  If you use the `compare` member of `std::string`, there's not even any reason to construct substrings.

Comment: Try to make the conditions to test that statement, i might be not using the best solution, but i think its still better than using compare, since that will give a negative, positive or 0 value, and you will need to compare each possible value to make the ranges that the user post in the code. I really think that @James Kanze answer would be better to enhance the code performance.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (c.compare( 0, 2, "65" ) == 0 || ... || (c.compare( 0, 6, "622126" ) >= 0 || c.compare( 0, 6, "622925") <= 0...`?

Comment: Nothing is wring about this. Who said that?

Answer (score 0):

Although not the most effective way of doing it, the only
problem I see in your code is that you're taking too many
characters in some of the cases: `c.substr(0, 5) == "6011"` can
only be true if `c.size() == 4`.

For what it's worth, I'd declare the prefixes as `static
std::string const` and use `std::equal` on them (after first
having checked that the number is long enough).  Alternatively,
I'd use a switch on the first character:

```
switch (c[0])
{
case '6':
    //  Additional tests for Discover...
    break;
case '5':
    //  Additional tests for MasterCard...
    break;

case '4':
    //  Additional tests for Visa...
    break;

case '3':
    //  Additional tests for American express..
    break;
}
```

Or even more likely, I'd use regular expressions, with the
patterns read from a configuration file; this is *not* the type
of information you want to hard code into a program.

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method returns a string, which can be [compared](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/) to another string. So far, your code looks fine.

For using brackets, look at [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). As I understand the code, you don't need brackets in your if conditions. But if you're in doubt, use brackets to make your intention clear.

You don't need to pass the length of the credit card number, since `checkCC` can determine this itself. Also pass the credit card number as

```
string checkCC(const string &c, ...)
```

because this avoids a copy of the string.